# Ambiguous use of 'subscript(_:)' when trying to retrieve users from my FireBase Database

Tags: swift, firebase, dictionary, swift5, for-in-loop

Like the description says I'm trying to retrieve users info from my Firebase Database and append them to my array I created but im getting  the "Ambiguous use of 'subscript(_:)'" error in my for in loop

˚

```
func getArtist(){  

        let reference = Database.database().reference()

        reference.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  { snapshot in



            let users = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]

            self.artistArray.removeAll()

            for (_,value) in users {

                if let artistId = value["uid"] as? String {
                    if artistId != Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid{
                        let artistShown = Artist()
                        if let userName = value["full_name"] as? String, let imagePath = value["urlToImage"] as? String {
                            artistShown.UserName = userName
                            artistShown.pathToImage = imagePath
                            artistShown.ArtistId = artistId
                            self.artistArray.append(artistShown)
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            self.ArtistView.reloadData()

        })
        reference.removeAllObservers()
    }


˚
```

I've also attached A ScreenShot to show Where I'm getting the error

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrNDT.png)

Comment: If `users` is a `[String: AnyObject]`, what is `value` in your for loop? It's a `AnyObject`. Why should then an `AnyObject` have a subscript method, meaning, you can do `["something"]` on it? You might need to do `if let dict = value as? ["String:" Any]`; and then play with `dict`.

Comment: Makes Complete Sense and worked like a charm! Thanks Larme